# SQL Server execution plan and estimated number of rows

Tags: sql-server, casting, sql-execution-plan

For example now I have a query like:

```
select * from A1 left join A2 on A1.Column1 = A2.Column1
left join A3 on A1.Column2 = A3.Column2 
left join A4 on A1.Column3 = A4.Column3 
....
left join A20 on A1.Column4 = A20.Column4
```

When I view the execution plan of above query, SQL Server show that It will firstly left join A1 with A2, then continue left join the result with A3...And after left join 20 tables, estimated number of rows haven't changed (2,1 millions)

But, if I change my query to:

```
select * from A1 left join A2 on Cast(A1.Column1 as bigint) = Cast(A2.Column1 as bigint)
left join A3 on Cast(A1.Column2 as bigint) = Cast(A3.Column2 as bigint)
left join A4 on Cast(A1.Column3 as bigint) = Cast(A4.Column3 as bigint)
....
left join A20 on Cast(A1.Column4 as bigint) = Cast(A20.Column4 as bigint)
```

Note: All my columns can be cast to bigint because it contain only number, but sometime it has leading zero so I have to let it data type as varchar.

Now, with this query, SQL server show that it will firstly left join A1 with A3, then with A4,A6,A7,A8,A10...A20 then A2, A17...About estimated number of rows, after join 13 tables, estimated number of rows haven't changed, but after that, each time it join another table, estimated number of rows increase dramatically, from 2 millions to 2,6 then 3,8..and after join 20 table it became 83 millions.

Can anybody explain why were this happen ? In my second query, why Sql server join table randomly like that? And what can make estimated number of rows suddenly increase like that?

Comment: not an answer but, joining on ints is orders of magnitude faster than joining on strings...

Comment: Yes, I know that, that 's the reason why I try to cast my columns to int. It really make join performance increase a lot. But after finish join, I have to insert the result into a table, and because the estimated number of rows increase dramatically like that, it cost a lot of time to sort and insert to new table and even slower than not cast to int.

Comment: There are few things to check. first how much data is available on each table? maybe your first table has 100 million record and though first 13 table match only 20, but next 7 table match other 80million record? I suggest first create few rows table and authenticate your data is correct.

Comment: can you add a `persisted computed column` to hold there the casted columns to int or bigint? It should help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that your cast is confusing the query optimizer with regard to the statistics - as with string sorting '201' will be between '2' and '3' - whereas for bigint it won't be. So, equally, if you had a string range from '1000' to '2' - then that doesn't make much sense as a bigint range.

I would strongly consider storing the integer version of the data as well, so that the statistics that are stored can make sense, and then you are likely to get better values out of the query optimizer.